# Minecraft Forge / Не получается синхронизировать клиент и сервер

Tags: java, minecraft, forge

Возможно, проблема даже и не в этом, однако я не знаю, по какой причине ещё мой код не работает как надо.

**Задача**: Написать мод Minecraft 1.12.2, нажимающий от имени игрока ПКМ при наличии на экране в поле `title bar` (не знаю, как по-русски называется) числа 6.

**Код:**

Импорты:

```
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiIngame;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.ClientRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ObfuscationReflectionHelper;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventPriority;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
```

Объявление всех полей и т.д.:

```
public class ExampleMod {
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String NAME = "Example Mod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
    public static KeyBinding[] keyBindings = { new KeyBinding("key.toggleMod.desc", Keyboard.KEY_RMENU, "key.categories.mod") };
    private boolean modEnabled = false;
    private Field displayedTitleField;
    private final Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
```

Инициализация во время запуска клиента. Добавил поиск displayedTitleField сразу сюда из-за того, что говорят, что `ObfuscationReflectionHelper` довольно медленный, поэтому лучше употребить его один раз:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        ClientRegistry.registerKeyBinding(keyBindings[0]);
        displayedTitleField = ObfuscationReflectionHelper.findField(GuiIngame.class, "field_175201_x");
        displayedTitleField.setAccessible(true);
    }
```

Код симуляции включения/выключения мода:

```
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) {
        if (keyBindings[0].isPressed()) {
            modEnabled = !modEnabled;
            EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
            player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString(modEnabled ? "Mod enabled!" : "Mod disabled!"));
        }
    }
```

Проблемная часть. Метод `onTick`, который вызывается каждый тик. Если текущее значение `currentTitle` содержит "a6" (a - код цвета перед символом 6, для того, чтобы на другие шестёрки не триггерился), то происходит клик ПКМ и мод "выключается". `assert currentTitle != null;` - затычка для того, чтобы не выбрасывался `NullPointerException`, её потом уберу (однако если уберёте вы, то возражать не буду :) ). `currentTitle` действительно равно текущему значению в `title bar`на экране, в этом я убеждался с помощью `mc.player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Current displayedTitle: " + currentTitle));`, которое тоже является временной затычкой.

```
    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.NORMAL, receiveCanceled = true)
    public void onTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
        if (event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.START) {
            if (modEnabled) {
                String currentTitle = getCurrentTitle();
                assert currentTitle != null;
                mc.player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Current displayedTitle: " + currentTitle));
                if (currentTitle.contains("a6")) {
                    mc.playerController.processRightClick(mc.player, mc.world, EnumHand.MAIN_HAND);
                    modEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод получения текста из `title bar`:

```
    public String getCurrentTitle() {
        try {
            GuiIngame ingameGUI = mc.ingameGUI;
            if (ingameGUI != null) {
                String displayedTitle = (String) displayedTitleField.get(ingameGUI);
                return displayedTitle != null ? displayedTitle : "";
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что в моём случае на экране появляются случайные числа от 1 до 6 с периодичностью в 4 тика. И мой мод либо нажимает слишком рано ПКМ, либо, наоборот, опаздывает в несколько тиков, я не знаю, но практически всегда он нажимает ПКМ невпопад - когда на экране уже не 6, а другое число.

Я пробовал использовать метод `onRenderGameOverlay`, однако даже несмотря на то, что в нём итераций получается больше, чем на 20 тиков в секунду, "кликается" ПКМ не вовремя.

Полный код для тех, кто хочет скопировать сразу всё:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiIngame;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.text.TextComponentString;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.ClientRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ObfuscationReflectionHelper;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventPriority;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, name = ExampleMod.NAME, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod {
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String NAME = "Example Mod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";
    public static KeyBinding[] keyBindings = { new KeyBinding("key.toggleMod.desc", Keyboard.KEY_RMENU, "key.categories.mod") };
    private boolean modEnabled = false;
    private Field displayedTitleField;
    private final Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        ClientRegistry.registerKeyBinding(keyBindings[0]);
        displayedTitleField = ObfuscationReflectionHelper.findField(GuiIngame.class, "field_175201_x");
        displayedTitleField.setAccessible(true);
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) {
        if (keyBindings[0].isPressed()) {
            modEnabled = !modEnabled;
            EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().player;
            player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString(modEnabled ? "Mod enabled!" : "Mod disabled!"));
        }
    }

    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.NORMAL, receiveCanceled = true)
    public void onTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
        if (event.phase == TickEvent.Phase.START) {
            if (modEnabled) {
                String currentTitle = getCurrentTitle();
                assert currentTitle != null;
                mc.player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Current displayedTitle: " + currentTitle));
                if (currentTitle.contains("a6")) {
                    mc.playerController.processRightClick(mc.player, mc.world, EnumHand.MAIN_HAND);
                    modEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public String getCurrentTitle() {
        try {
            GuiIngame ingameGUI = mc.ingameGUI;
            if (ingameGUI != null) {
                String displayedTitle = (String) displayedTitleField.get(ingameGUI);
                return displayedTitle != null ? displayedTitle : "";
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```